# How to keep the busy indicator working during data binding?

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls

While fetching data or running some other long task on a separate thread the busy indicator is spinning fine but once the long running task is complete and the data binding to a collection used by the UI starts the busy indicator freezes...

Now, the busy indicator and the data binding both work on the UI thread so it makes sense but I keep thinking that there's got a be a way of keeping the busy indicator working during data binding... I'm assuming one of the two would have to work on a different thread but that doesn't seam to be possible...

I'm currently using Telerik controls but I had the same problem with busy indicators from other collections so it's not unique to Telerik.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is there any way to constrain the data binding so that you don't need a busy indicator, perhaps with paging?  I would imagine users would be impatient with a data binding operation that is that slow.

Comment: I so hope you find an answer but my experience is once it starts to render (e.g. bind) the UI is frozen until it renders.  It binds on the main (UI) thread.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, but I have to give users the option of deciding how much data they want to fetch and how they want to see the data... a lot of people do not like paging...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228175/displaying-a-busy-indicator-when-entity-framework-is-loading-data

Comment: I don't agree that users are opposed to paging itself.  If paging is fast they tend to like it.  For speed I pre fetch the next page and hold the prior.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That question is not even close to what I'm asking, I have no problem spinning the busy indicator while EF operations are running...

Comment: I don't understand... Presumably the data in your data binding operations is coming from somewhere.  It may not be EF, but the principles should be the same.

Comment: @DeanK. You should profile what's really freezing the main thread. In my experience it rarely is the databinding itself that causes problem: this is actually quite fast. It's either too much computation (like transforming DTOs to models: do that on another thread), or lack of virtualization of lists. In Telerik case, their WPF controls are quite slow to show the first time even with no data, especially with a non default theme since they change the DefaultStyleKey, invalidating a bunch of WPF cache. This was a year ago though, it may have changed.

Comment: @RobertHarvey While the data is being fetched on a background thread the busy indicator is spinning, it is after the data is fetched and converted to POCOs on a background thread that the busy indicators freezes as the data binding starts...

Comment: Does the `ExecuteBackgroundProcess` method described by the linked post offer a possible solution?

Comment: So you're saying we could start spinning the busy indicator using the TPL... I assumed that was not possible but I'll give it a try...